# Firebase Storage putBytes throwing StorageException: Cannot upload to getRoot

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-storage

I have the following method to try to upload an image as a byte array to firebase storage in Kotlin, but it's throwing a StorageException.

```
private val storageReference = Firebase.storage.reference

private suspend fun uploadProfilePicture(profilePicture: ByteArray) {
    val completableDeferred = CompletableDeferred<Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>>()
    storageReference.child("users/${auth.currentUser!!.uid}/profile_picture.jpg")
    storageReference.putBytes(profilePicture)
        .addOnCompleteListener { task -> completableDeferred.complete(task) }
    val uploadResult = completableDeferred.await()
    if (!uploadResult.isSuccessful) 
        throw UploadException(uploadResult.exception?.message ?: "Profile picture was not uploaded")
}
```

The logcat error:

```
  An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response.
   Code: -13000 HttpResult: 0
2021-03-18 21:14:47.586 16532-16532/ E/StorageException: Cannot upload to getRoot. You should upload to a storage location such as .getReference('image.png').putFile...
  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot upload to getRoot. You should upload to a storage location such as .getReference('image.png').putFile...
    at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(UploadTask.java:205)
    at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.lambda$getRunnable$7(StorageTask.java:1072)
    at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$$Lambda$12.run(Unknown Source:2)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
2021-03-18 21:14:47.587 16532-16532/ E/Register upload: An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response.
```

Following https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files#kotlin+ktx this seems to be fine, I'm not sure what the problem could be. And the security rules on my storage are set to allow anyone as long as they are authorised at the moment:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling the `putBytes()` method on the root reference. That is not allowed. Create a child reference using the root reference as  `val reference = storageReference.child("users/${auth.currentUser!!.uid}/profile_picture.jpg")` and call `putBytes()` method on it (`reference.putBytes(profilePicture)`).

The modified code will look like this.

```
private val storageReference = Firebase.storage.reference

private suspend fun uploadProfilePicture(profilePicture: ByteArray) {
    val completableDeferred = CompletableDeferred<Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>>()
    val reference = storageReference.child("users/${auth.currentUser!!.uid}/profile_picture.jpg")
    reference.putBytes(profilePicture)
        .addOnCompleteListener { task -> completableDeferred.complete(task) }
    val uploadResult = completableDeferred.await()
    if (!uploadResult.isSuccessful) 
        throw UploadException(uploadResult.exception?.message ?: "Profile picture was not uploaded")
}
```